# Empty text field set to null in symfony2 form

Tags: forms, symfony

I've a form with a text field. This field maps to a not nullable field in my DB (is a legacy DB and I can't change this)

The problem is that Symfony2 always set empty text field to `NULL` and, this make the insert fails.

Is there a way to tell Symfony2 to not set empty text fields to `NULL` ?

Comment: set it in the entity for example  `* @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)`

Comment: @hous: I want to insert empty string, not null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by setting a blank value by default in the entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="example", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $example = '';
```

As for your issue, unfortunately [you are describing a known issue/bug with Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5906), so you'll have to override the value being set to the setter function:

```
public function setExample($example = null) {
    if (empty($example)) {
        $example = '';
    }
    $this->example = $example;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this already but doesn't work ! Symfony sets empty strings to `null`

Comment: Yes. Things works that way. But is see it as an hack/workaround. I would like Symfony to not set the field to `null`. I've changed you example. Please accept it.

Comment: @Hpatoio I'd be cautious about using a direct type comparison in case `$example` is `false` or some other empty value, or else Symfony may send a `null` value to the database again. I'm going to reference a known bug in an edit.

Comment: I didn't know about that bug. BTW, I don't think your code fix this the problem. If Symfony calls somewhere `$myEntity->setExample(null)` I still get `null` in my DB. And this is what I don't want. Do you agree ?

Comment: @Hpatoio Please leave the answer as-is, it's meant to also help other readers that may end up on your question. If you remove the `= null` portion from the method declaration, you will get errors if you try to use `$entity->setExample()` without a value (which is supposed to be a valid call for setting an empty value.) `empty()` works better than `is_null()` because it accounts for `false`, `null`, and `0` - all of which values could be (but not necessarily will be) typecasted into `null` when being stored into the database.

Comment: FYI, this Symfony issue is solved in v3.1, by: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/18357 Or, if you're stuck with previous versions, use this fix: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5906#issuecomment-194201078

Answer (score 2):

The code below works for me. I tune the form definition.

```
    $builder->add('comment', TextareaType::class, [
        'empty_data'    => '',
        'required'      => false,
    ]);
```